# Inverse of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> I want an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $\det A=1$ such that when I multiply it with a normalized vector $v$ I get $e_1$.

Initially I interpreted the problem as just rotating the vector along each axis till it gets aligned with a particular axis. Then I read about rotations in higher dimensions and understood that the problem is not as easy as it seems. Rotations in higher dimensions do not work like that.

Is there any other way to approach this problem? Numerical methods perhaps?

**EDIT:**
I wanted to generate n, n dimensional vectors such that their dot products are zero.

I thought, if I could rotate the vector along each axis by multiplying it with corresponding rotation matrices. Say for 3 dimensional space, $R_x$, $R_y$ and $R_z$ such that I get $e_1$. Then that would imply that $IR^{-1}$ is a matrix containing vectors which are perpendicular to each other and contain the given vector. However it turned out that matrix multiplication in higher dimensions is complicated.

I found the solution in [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Answer (score 0):

Choose an orthonormal basis such that $v=e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n$ and consider the matrix $A$ the *rows* of which are given by the $e_i^T$ (transposed vectors). It's easy to see that then $Av = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$ and $\det(A)=1 $ is true since such an $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The geometry is easier than the algebra. Let $P$ be the plane containing $v$ and $e_1$. $P$ is a two dimensional subspace (if it's a line then $v$ was $\pm e_1$ to begin with.) Find the $n-2$ dimensional subspace $Q$ orthogonal to $P$. Then define $A$ as the rotation you need in $P$ and the identity on $Q$.

Comment: @user26857 Yes. I edited the answer to make this clearer.